# Time to upload 100GB to Amazon Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

How much time amazon glacier will take to upload 100GB of archive using aws multipart upload (Using AWSSDK)

What are the parameters needs to be considered to increase the upload speed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would depend upon the speed of your Internet connection.

While AWS might throttle your access to the service, your Internet connection is likely to be the biggest bottleneck.

The best way to know is to upload some data (eg a few GB) and test the speed yourself.